# How to get gradient of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

I am new to derivatives of linear equation systems. And I would like to

$$\|Ax-b\|^2 = (Ax-b)^T(Ax-b) (equation)$$

And how do I reach to this gradient: $\Delta_x = 2(Ax-b)^TA$?

If I develop the equation I get: $Ax^TAx-b^TAx-Ax^Tb+b$. But how do I get to the gradient ?

Comment: Your expansion is not correct, it should be $x^T A^T A x - x^TA^T b - b^T Ax +b^T b$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=||Ax-b||^2$.

Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
f(x+h)-f(x) & = & ||Ax-b +Ah||^2 -||Ax-b||^2 & \\
&=& (Ah)^T (Ax-b) + (Ax-b)^T Ah + (Ah)^T (Ah) & \\
&=& (Ah)^T (Ax-b) + (Ax-b)^T Ah &\text{neglecting the $||h||^2$ terms}\\ 
&=& (Ax-b)^T Ah + (Ax-b)^T Ah &\text{since $(Ah)^T (Ax-b)$ is $1\times 1$}\\
&&&\text{and so symmetric.}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

That is, 
$$
f(x+h)-f(x)= 2(Ax-b)^T A h+ O(||h||^2),
$$
so the gradient is $2(Ax-b)^T A$.

Answer (score 1):

This question comes up often, and the most elegant solution uses the chain rule. Let $f(x) = \| Ax - b ||_2^2$. Note that $f(x) = g(h(x))$, where $h(x) = Ax - b$ and $g(u) = \| u \|^2$. The derivatives of $h$ and $g$ are $h'(x) = A$ and $g'(u) = 2u^T$ (a row vector). By the chain rule,
$$
f'(x) = g'(h(x)) h'(x) = 2(Ax - b)^T A.
$$